# Property and name at runtime from a class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class

```
public class ProjectTask
{
    public ProjectTask();


    [XmlElement("task_creator_id")]
    public string task_creator_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_owner_id")]
    public string task_owner_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_owner_location")]
    public TaskOwnerLocation task_owner_location { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_owner_type")]
    public string task_owner_type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_type_description")]
    public string task_type_description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_type_id")]
    public string task_type_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("task_type_name")]
    public string task_type_name { get; set; }
}
```

An xml will be deserialized to this at runtime.

Is there way to get the field name and value?

Using reflection I can get the property names like so:

```
PropertyInfo[] projectAttributes = typeof(ProjectTask).GetProperties();
```

A foreach loop can be applied to get the properties

```
foreach(PropertyInfo taskName in projectAttributes)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(taskName.Name);
       }
```

but how do I print the property and the value?
Like 
    task_creator_id = 1

where task_Id is one of the properties and the value of that at runtime is 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Treat Object Like Dictionary of Properties in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652560/treat-object-like-dictionary-of-properties-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `taskName.GetValue(yourObject,null)`

where `yourObject` should be of an instance of `ProjectTask`. For ex,

```
ProjectTask yourObject = (ProjectTask)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream)

var propDict = typeof(ProjectTask)
                  .GetProperties()
                  .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(yourObject, null));
```

Comment: Thanks L.B, that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using your `PropertyInfo` object :

```
var propertyName = MyPropertyInfoObject.Name;
var propertyValue = MyPropertyInfoObject.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

A foreach loop give you access to all properties of your type, you can also have a specefic property knowing its name, like so :

```
var MyPropertyInfoObject = myType.GetProperty("propertyName");
```

Comment: The foreach loop gets the name but gives Object does not match target type error

Comment: You can do a cast to the returned object