# Flatten list of list using linq or other C# functions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class:

```
    public class ChartData
    {        
      public Decimal? Value { get; set; }        
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    }
```

And I have also

```
    List<List<ChartData>> chartData = List<List<ChartData>>();
```

chartData can contains any number of List, it could be one, but also it could be ten lists.

I need this structure flattened. For example if I have two lists in chartData I need to get list of objects where each object contains fields:

```
    {
      Decimal? Value0
      Decimal? Value1
      DateTime Date
    }
```

if I have ten lists I need to get list of objects where each object contains fields:

```
    {
      Decimal? Value0
      Decimal? Value1
      .
      .
      .
      Decimal? Value9
      DateTime Date
    }
```

Is it possible to do it using linq or other C# functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is right: `public Decimal? Value { get; set; }`? How is that "any number of List"? Is it supposed to be `public IList<decimal?> Values { get; set; }` or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

If `chartData` can really contain *any* number of lists, you are out of luck, since you cannot dynamically create fields in a .NET class. The exact structure of a class must be known at compile time, even if it is an anonymous class.

You might consider using

```
{
    List<Decimal?> Values,
    DateTime Date
}
```

or

```
{
    Decimal?[] Values,
    DateTime Date
}
```

instead, which can both be created easily via LINQ. If you elaborate on *why* you need them to be separate fields *(Maybe some kind of serialization requirement? If yes, which format?)*, the SO community might be able to suggest an alternative solution. In addition, you should specify which *Date* value should be used, if they differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dynamic possibilities of C# introduced in version 4.0.

See this [SO article on property bags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9653052/880990).

Note however, that you lose any compiletime checks! Consider it twice, before you do that.